# Biblatex: Cannot switch from Chicaco to APA style - undefined control sequence 'mkbibdateapalongextra'

Tags: biblatex, apa-style

On the request of a publisher, I am trying to change from Chicago style bibliography to APA style. I had this working fine:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago}
```

I have tried this:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,authordate,style=apa]{biblatex}
```

It fails with

```
! Package xkeyval Error: `authordate' undefined in families `blx@opt@pre'.
```

I remove `authordate`:

```
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex}
```

It compiles first, but then after I ran Biber, it fails with

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \mkbibdateapalongextra 
                               {year}{month}{day}\iffieldundef {endyear}{...
```

Example:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[UKenglish]{babel}
\usepackage[lf]{venturis}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[backend=biber,authordate]{biblatex-chicago} % works
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=apa]{biblatex} % doesn't work

\begin{filecontents*}{foo.bib} 
@article{denning2010computation,
    AUTHOR      = {Denning, Peter J.},
    TITLE       = {What is Computation?},
    JOURNAL     = {Ubiquity},
    YEAR        = {2010},
    DOI         = {10.1145/1880066.1880067}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{foo.bib}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage[shrink=10, babel=true]{microtype}   

\begin{document}
foo \autocite{denning2010computation}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate. To fix the issue, one has to add this line:

```
\DeclareLanguageMapping{british}{british-apa}
```